# T-SQL Conditional Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So this isn't really a normal conditional select statement.

I current there is a column `ID` and a column `Number`. Either `ID` is 0 or `Number` is 0.

So my select statement needs to do Select colA, colB, colC, `crazy part` From Table A.

the `crazy part` is this:
`(If ID > 0, ID, Number)` basically select and return that column that isn't 0.
Is there any way to do this in T-SQL?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should do it:

```
select colA, colB, colC, case when ID is 0 then Number else ID end as Crazy
from TableA
```

Answer (score 3):

`CASE` (as explained by others) certainly works. However, if one of the two is always 0, you could also just add them together.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CASE` statement:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is CASE

Answer (score 0):

You would do this using a [`CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement:

```
SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    colC,
    CASE WHEN ID > 0 THEN ID ELSE Number END
FROM
   TableA
```